# Replace a href link with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a method in which I can replace an established link by using jQuery

```
    <ul class="navigation"
    <li class="level0 nav-1 level-top first parent">
    <a href="mylink.com/whats-new.html" class="level-top"><span>What's New</span></a>
    </li>
    ...
```

Ideally I'd like to replace the link with javascript:void(0) without affecting any other items.

Some expert help would be really appreciated.

Thank you very much

PS: I've tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    });
    </script>
```

earlier. This works but affects all links.

Comment: what do you mean? Affects other?

Comment: *"I'd like to replace the link with javascript:void(0)"* i don't see any such links in the shared `HTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment,

You can just do this by using selector `.nav-1 a`, which targets `<a>` which are descedents of `.nav-1`

```
$('.nav-1 a').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
```

But, I would suggest you to prevent the default action

```
$('.nav-1 a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Amit, I've tried a similar method earlier and it works, however it will affect all items. I only want to affect nav-1 ideally

Comment: @TJ suggestion incorporated ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul.navigation a').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
     $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0)");

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the url of a specific anchor tag then you have to provide the relevant selector of that element.

**jQuery code**

```
$(".navigation li.first a.level-top").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
```

or

```
$("a[href=mylink.com/whats-new.html]").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
```